# Are achievements 'unlocked', 'completed' or [...]?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

So in a game when you do a specific task you might 'unlock' or 'complete' an achievement, so which one is more correct or more commonly used?

Take the following sentence:

> You have [...] the achievement 'First things First'!

If there is a better alternative that would be suited, then that is welcome too.

Comment: You can say "You have achieved 'First things First!'"

Comment: Usually "unlock" is a result where future play becomes possible.  So achieving First Things First may cause other things to be unlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have some experience with gaming, I can see a few options of how to express it which depend on what is being achieved, unlocked, etc. To keep it consistent, even though the *name* may not make sense in the sentence, I will use your name of 'First things First' in all examples.

If, for example, the object is some challenge or task which they have successfully completed, you can say:

> You have *completed* 'First things First'!

Or

> You have *passed* 'First things First'!

If the object is an award, similar to a trophy, or a privilege, such as free admittance to a guild hall, you could say:

> You have *earned* 'First things First'!

Or, possibly

> You have *been granted* 'First things First'!

If the object is some status, such as becoming the top ranked mage, you could say:

> You have *achieved* 'First things First'!

If the object is some skill developed through normal play, say the ability to use a throwing weapons, you can say:

> You have *learned* 'First things First'!

Lastly, if the object is something related more to the game, or a game within the game, such as allowing advanced levels of play, or the ability to purchase items that didn't exist before, you could say:

> You have *unlocked* 'First things First'!

I would tend to reserve *unlocked* for cases where something has now become possible which was not possible prior to completing something specific and unique. The mere gaining of experience, or levels would not normally qualify for "unlocking" something.

Comment: Thanks, contextually providing sentences helps a lot to figure out the answer.